# Connecting SQLIte3 database to Tkinter listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I've been trying to connect the data in my SQLite3 database to display in a listbox object. Right now, data displays but its only data that is hardcoded into the program. I have a database with two columns: Name and Price, and I simply want it to display the name on each line of the listbox. I'm at a loss of what to do, any help would be great.

```
    def create_connection(db_file):

try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect("shopping.sqlite")
    return conn
except Error as e:
    print(e)

return None

def select_all(conn):

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM shopping")

rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row)

# load the listbox with data
for item in shopping:
    listbox1.insert(tk.END, item)
```

Comment: please fix the indentation, and create a [mcve]

Comment: "conn" is local to create_connection, so is garbage collected when the function exits.  "for item in shopping:" --> you don't declare shopping anywhere.  Also, print type(row) as well as row as we don't know what type you think it is.  http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_sqlite_in_python_tutorial.html